# Are they the same? "to sit / lie there" vs "to sit / lie on there"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Are they the same? "to sit / lie here" vs "to sit / lie on here"?

"**There**" can be a noun or an adverb

> > **[there](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/there)** [noncount] 1  : that place
> >
> > *Get away from there.*

---

> [there](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/there) 2 /ðeə $ ðer/ ●●● S1 W1 adverb     1 in or to a particular place
>   that is not where you are → here
>
> We could go back to my cottage and have lunch there.
>
> Scotland? I’ve always wanted to go there.
>
> Hold it right there and don’t move.
>
> Can you pass me that wine glass there?
>
> Look, there’s that bookshop I was telling you about.
>
> Who’s that man over there?
>
> It’s too far to drive there and back in one day.
>
> Are we going to get there (=arrive) before the banks close?
>
> **out/in/under etc there**   I know there’s a mouse under there somewhere.
>
> We flew to Miami and from there to La Paz.

---

Know that "**out / in / under / over /  up / near / around / down there**" are common but not sure if "**on there**" is common

My question is that?

Are they the same? "**to sit / lie there**" and "**to sit / lie on there**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sit/lie there** = in that place.

**sit/lie on there** = on that chair, bed, mat or whatever.